# How to open a network path folder in windows explorer on click of link from Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, directory, folder-access

I want to open a network path folder in windows explorer on click of a link from mozilla firefox. After research, came to know that opening a folder from Mozilla and chrome is not possible as like IE. Is there any way to write any click event in c# to make it done. I need to access a path in the network share. I tried Process.Start() but that gives server execution failed. I used   
as the clickable control.

Answer (score 0):

None of the modern browsers might allow this, I guess even IE would show some kind of warning or allow only in case IE is running with some low security setting. This is a big security risk and even if there are some hacks out there, this is not the kind of code you should expect to be going in production.